# Bending equation and max deflection of UDL and multiple point loads

Tags: structural-engineering, statics, beam, deflection

I have a beam, simply supported with 2 points loads and 2 UDLs. The loads are symmetric about the centre of the beam.

I've tried to derive an expression for the moment along the beam and then via 2 integrations obtained expressions for slope and deflection respectively.

Could someone please let me know whether I'm close with what I have or help me to create an overall moment equation, which i can plot in MathCAD preferably, and also help me with finding the maximum deflection of the beam? Attached is the FBD for the problem.

[image]

Below is my attempt at a solution for deflection (In the case where x = L).

[image]

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can we assume the loading is symmetrical? At a glance, it seems that the distance the second UDL covers past the right-most nodal force is smaller than the distance B marked on the other side.

Comment: Hey Wasabi - we can indeed assume that the loading is perfectly symmetric, my layout was a bit rushed...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I'll be using the following notation:

- $q_1, q_2$ are the distributed loads (where you use $w$, which I reserve for deflections)
- $L = c + 2(a+b)$, the total length of the span
- $\ell = a + b$

I'll also be making use of the structure and loading's symmetry, and adopting the following model:

[image: half of beam modelled by placing Rz support at midspan]

First let's get the reactions. Since the structure and the loading is symmetrical, this is trivial, with each support getting half of each load.

$$R = -\dfrac{q_1(L-2a)}{2} - \dfrac{q_2L}{2} - P$$

Let's then use singularity functions to describe the loading on the beam and integrate our way up to the deflection:

$$\begin{align}
\newcommand{\a}[1]{\langle #1 \rangle}
q &= R\a{x}^{-1} + q_1\a{x-a}^0 + q_2\a{x}^0 + P\a{x-\ell}^{-1} \\
Q &= R\a{x}^0 + q_1\a{x-a}^1 + q_2\a{x}^1 + P\a{x-\ell}^0 \\
M &= R\a{x}^1 + \dfrac{q_1\a{x-a}^2}{2} + \dfrac{q_2\a{x}^2}{2} + P\a{x-\ell}^1 \\
EI\theta &= \dfrac{R\a{x}^2}{2} + \dfrac{q_1\a{x-a}^3}{6} + \dfrac{q_2\a{x}^3}{6} + \dfrac{P\a{x-\ell}^2}{2} + C_1 \\
EIw &= \dfrac{R\a{x}^3}{6} + \dfrac{q_1\a{x-a}^4}{24} + \dfrac{q_2\a{x}^4}{24} + \dfrac{P\a{x-\ell}^3}{6} + C_1x + C_2 \\
\end{align}$$

Now let's use the boundary conditions to find those constants.

$$\begin{align}
\theta\left(\dfrac{L}{2}\right) = EI\theta ={}& \dfrac{R}{2}\left(\dfrac{L}{2}\right)^2 + \dfrac{q_1}{6}\left(\dfrac{L}{2}-a\right)^3 + \dfrac{q_2}{6}\left(\dfrac{L}{2}\right)^3 + \dfrac{P}{2}\left(\dfrac{L}{2}-\ell\right)^2 + C_1 = 0 \\
\therefore C_1 ={}& q_1\left(\dfrac{(L-2a)}{4}\left(\dfrac{L}{2}\right)^2 - \dfrac{1}{6}\left(\dfrac{L}{2}-a\right)^3\right) \\
&+ q_2\left(\dfrac{L}{4}\left(\dfrac{L}{2}\right)^2 - \dfrac{1}{6}\left(\dfrac{L}{2}\right)^3\right) \\
&+ P\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{L}{2}\right)^2 - \dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{L}{2}-\ell\right)^2\right) \\
={}& q_1\left(\dfrac{a^3}{6} - \dfrac{a^2L}{4} + \dfrac{L^3}{24}\right) \\
&+ \dfrac{q_2L^3}{24} \\
&+ \dfrac{P\ell(L-\ell)}{2} \\
w(0) = C_2 ={}& 0
\end{align}$$

We therefore have the full description of the entire beam. Personally, I prefer splitting the functions up for each beam segment. Therefore, we have:

For $x\in[0,a]$:

$$\begin{align}
Q ={}& R\a{x}^0 + q_2\a{x}^1 \\
={}& \dfrac{q_1(2a - L)}{2} \\
&+ q_2\left(x - \dfrac{L}{2}\right) \\
&- P \\
M ={}& R\a{x}^1 + \dfrac{q_2\a{x}^2}{2} \\
={}&\dfrac{q_1(2a - L)}{2}x \\
&+ q_2\left(\dfrac{1}{2}x^2 - \dfrac{L}{2}x\right)  \\
&- Px \\
EI\theta ={}& \dfrac{R\a{x}^2}{2} + \dfrac{q_2\a{x}^3}{6} + C_1 \\
={}&q_1\left(\dfrac{2a - L}{4}x^2 + \dfrac{a^3}{6} - \dfrac{a^2L}{4} + \dfrac{L^3}{24}\right) \\
&+ q_2\left(\dfrac{1}{6}x^3 - \dfrac{L}{4}x^2 + \dfrac{L^3}{24}\right) \\
&+ P\left(-\dfrac{1}{2}x^2 + \dfrac{\ell(L-\ell)}{2}\right) \\
EIw ={}& \dfrac{R\a{x}^3}{6} + \dfrac{q_2\a{x}^4}{24} + C_1x \\
={}&q_1\left(\dfrac{2a - L}{12}x^3 + \left(\dfrac{a^3}{6} - \dfrac{a^2L}{4} + \dfrac{L^3}{24}\right)x\right) \\
&+ q_2\left(\dfrac{1}{24}x^4 - \dfrac{L}{12}x^3 + \dfrac{L^3}{24}x\right) \\
&+ P\left(-\dfrac{1}{6}x^3 + \dfrac{\ell}{2}(L-\ell)x\right)
\end{align}$$

For $x\in(a,\ell]$:

$$\begin{align}
Q ={}& R\a{x}^0 + q_1\a{x-a}^1 + q_2\a{x}^1 \\
={}&q_1\left(x - \dfrac{L}{2}\right) \\
&+ q_2\left(x - \dfrac{L}{2}\right) \\
&- P \\
M ={}&R\a{x}^1 + \dfrac{q_1\a{x-a}^2}{2} + \dfrac{q_2\a{x}^2}{2} \\
={}&q_1\left(\dfrac{1}{2}x^2 - \dfrac{L}{2}x + \dfrac{a^2}{2}\right) \\
&+ q_2\left(\dfrac{1}{2}x^2 - \dfrac{L}{2}x\right)  \\
&- Px \\
EI\theta ={}&\dfrac{R\a{x}^2}{2} + \dfrac{q_1\a{x-a}^3}{6} + \dfrac{q_2\a{x}^3}{6} + C_1 \\
={}&q_1\left(\dfrac{1}{6}x^3 - \dfrac{L}{4}x^2 + \dfrac{a^2}{2}x - \dfrac{a^2L}{4} + \dfrac{L^3}{24}\right) \\
&+ q_2\left(\dfrac{1}{6}x^3 - \dfrac{L}{4}x^2 + \dfrac{L^3}{24}\right) \\
&+ P\left(-\dfrac{1}{2}x^2 + \dfrac{\ell(L-\ell)}{2}\right) \\
EIw ={}&\dfrac{R\a{x}^3}{6} + \dfrac{q_1\a{x-a}^4}{24} + \dfrac{q_2\a{x}^4}{24} + C_1x \\
={}&q_1\left(\dfrac{1}{24}x^4 - \dfrac{L}{12}x^3 + \dfrac{a^2}{4}x^2 + \left(\dfrac{L^3}{24} - \dfrac{a^2L}{4}\right)x + \dfrac{a^4}{24}\right) \\
&+ q_2\left(\dfrac{1}{24}x^4 - \dfrac{L}{12}x^3 + \dfrac{L^3}{24}x\right) \\
&+ P\left(-\dfrac{1}{6}x^3 + \dfrac{\ell}{2}(L-\ell)x\right)
\end{align}$$

And finally, for $x\in(\ell,\frac{L}{2}]$:

$$\begin{align}
Q ={}& R\a{x}^0 + q_1\a{x-a}^1 + q_2\a{x}^1 + P\a{x-\ell}^0 \\
={}&q_1\left(x - \dfrac{L}{2}\right) \\
&+ q_2\left(x - \dfrac{L}{2}\right) \\
&+ 0 \\
M ={}&R\a{x}^1 + \dfrac{q_1\a{x-a}^2}{2} + \dfrac{q_2\a{x}^2}{2} + P\a{x-\ell}^1 \\
={}&q_1\left(\dfrac{1}{2}x^2 - \dfrac{L}{2}x + \dfrac{a^2}{2}\right) \\
&+ q_2\left(\dfrac{1}{2}x^2 - \dfrac{L}{2}x\right)  \\
&-P\ell \\
EI\theta ={}&\dfrac{R\a{x}^2}{2} + \dfrac{q_1\a{x-a}^3}{6} + \dfrac{q_2\a{x}^3}{6} + \dfrac{P\a{x-\ell}^2}{2} + C_1 \\
={}&q_1\left(\dfrac{1}{6}x^3 - \dfrac{L}{4}x^2 + \dfrac{a^2}{2}x - \dfrac{a^2L}{4} + \dfrac{L^3}{24}\right) \\
&+ q_2\left(\dfrac{1}{6}x^3 - \dfrac{L}{4}x^2 + \dfrac{q_2L^3}{24}\right) \\
&+ P\left(-\ell x + \dfrac{L\ell}{2}\right) \\
EIw ={}&\dfrac{R\a{x}^3}{6} + \dfrac{q_1\a{x-a}^4}{24} + \dfrac{q_2\a{x}^4}{24} + \dfrac{P\a{x-\ell}^3}{6} + C_1x \\
={}&q_1\left(\dfrac{1}{24}x^4 - \dfrac{L}{12}x^3 + \dfrac{a^2}{4}x^2 + \left(\dfrac{L^3}{24} - \dfrac{a^2L}{4}\right)x + \dfrac{a^4}{24}\right) \\
&+ q_2\left(\dfrac{1}{24}x^4 - \dfrac{L}{12}x^3 + \dfrac{L^3}{24}x\right) \\
&+ P\left(-\dfrac{\ell}{2}x^2 + \dfrac{L\ell}{2}x - \dfrac{\ell^3}{6}\right)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Grat for investing so much work into the answer.

Comment: Hi Wasabi - Thanks very much for your effort here - it's much appreciated. I used the exact same approach to get the equation for the beam and integrated using singularity functions. Somehow I came to a different answer! I'll check my algebra...Thanks again!

Comment: @richyo1000, or check mine! I'm fairly certain mine is correct, but typos happen to the best of us, so they certainly happen to me as well. Also make sure you use some sort of analytical math software or website (I used WolframAlpha) to help simplify the equations, since you'll actually get some pretty ugly initial results which can be simplified substantially.

Comment: Thanks Wasabi - I've checked them and they all work out. You've put a lot of (tedious!) work into this so thanks very much for that  :)

Comment: Hi Wasabi - I have just noticed something (must have been asleep when I looked at this earlier!) - You seem to only have one 'P' load - have you combined the two somewhere that I'm not seeing?

Comment: @richyo1000: The 'P' represents just one of the concentrated loads. That's because I'm using the half-beam model, so there's actually just one concentrated load to think of! Since I use $\theta(L/2)=0$ as one of the boundary conditions, this guarantees that the result is equivalent to the model with the other concentrated load.

Comment: Smart! I’d not considered using a half model-does that mean I have to double any result I get from the moment slope and deflection equations you stated?

Comment: @richyo1000: Nope. The half-beam model is a perfect representation of the entire beam. Just think about it: a simply-supported beam with symmetrical loading will have no rotation at the midspan. If you know this, there's no reason why you can't cut the beam in half and place a fixed roller at midspan: the loading on that half will cause exactly the same stresses and deflections to the half-beam as all the loading causes on the full beam. Obviously, if you're dealing with non-symmetrical loading, you can't make this simplification, which is why I asked for the clarification on your question.

Comment: Of course, that makes sense! It’s been a long couple of weeks-thanks for your help and advice Wasabi!